# WooCommerce Booking add email notification for booking asset chosen by customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress with WooCommerce and WooCommerce Bookings and Appoints plugins. It allows customers to choose date/time and an employee (booking asset) to work with. A notification is sent to the customer and admin of the website.  I need the employee to be notified as well.  When setting up the booking asset (employee) there is no field for email address.  Nor is there a way to cc someone else on the email notifications settings. Looking for an automated way to address this.
Here is what the booking asset page looks like when you are setting it up.
[booking assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJH1e.png)
Employees can overlap on time slots, so each employee needs their own email.

Comment: This question is not really answerable, as it's related to a third party commercial plugin and you should provide in your question your own real code attempt.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  I was mostly wondering if anyone had gone through this before.  I bet they have. Right now I am being paid to find out possible solutions but not code.  Which really puts me in a bind. My next step would naturally be to create a child theme (there isn't one) and add code to the functions file. But my client really does not want a "hard code" solution.  He would rather work with plugins already created.  I have my serious doubts that is a solution like that.  Just thought I would post this to see if anyone else has faced this and had a solution.

Comment: Your client or yourself must need to hire a skilled developer to solve that kind of complicated things.